# Either X(s) or Y(s) is/are

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I am confused on how to formulate sentences with (n)either...(n)or and the form of verb.

Which sentence is gramatically correct?

"Either my uncle or aunt are visiting me today"
"Either my uncle or aunt is visiting me today"

"Neither chocolates nor cake are sufficient for the birthday party"
"Neither chocolates nor cake is sufficient for the birthday party"

"Either the dog or the cats are going to the pound"
"Either the dog or the cats is going to the pound"

Comment: I couldn't find what I thought was a reasonable duplicate, even in the automatically related questions.

Answer (score 3):

*Either* presents a choice. The verb depends on **what is being chosen,** not that there are a number of options.

> Either my uncle or my aunt...

Here, both your uncle and aunt are singular. They will come alone. So it's *Either my uncle or my aunt **is.***

> Either the Joneses or the Phillipses...

Here, both the options are plural: the Jones family or the Philips family. Whoever arrives, it will be a number of people. So it's *Either the Joneses or the Philipses **are.***

Where there is some latitude is where the number differs between the choices.

> Neither chocolates nor cake...
>   Either the dog or the cats

In this case, the verb tends to agree with the choice which is nearest. So *cake* is a mass noun and requires *is;* *cats* is a plural noun and requires *are*.

Having said that, because there is some latitude, you may find that the "wrong" verb sounds better. I'm sure I would say "Neither chocolates nor cake are enough".

Equally, if you reverse the dog/cats choice, "Either the cats or the dog..." then *is* sounds very odd, but *are* doesn't sound right either. Many people would instinctively change the verb so it's no longer number-sensitive, or change the choice to include the verb:

> Either the cats or the dog will have to go.
>   Either the cats go or the dog does!

Comment: A good resource to go alongside this: http://www.elearnenglishlanguage.com/blog/english-mistakes/either-and-neither/